# How To show custom Properties on an IdentityUser List using MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display the contents of custom User properties on a User Index.

I added the `employee_id` and `name` which are already on the database and I save on user Creation.

The problem is that when listing the Users I can not access those properties.

I have de Following `ApplicationUser` Class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public string employee_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

This is the Controller:

```
    private IdentityDbContext identityDb = new IdentityDbContext();

    //GET: /Account/Index
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = identityDb.Users.Include(u => u.Roles).ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
```

This is the View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Employee Id
        </th>        
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.employee_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Email displays as expected but when adding `employee_id`, it is marked as non existant on Visual Studio.

How can I make custom properties accesible so that I can list them on an Index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>
```

To this:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourNamespace.ApplicationUser>
```